# looking for a help(in wordpress) on how to parse JSON encoded object at server side (PHP code)?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, wordpress

Though I have searched a lot, I was not able to get a concrete answer

## client side code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery("#p_button").click ( function () {
   console.log("button got clicked");
   var donor_data= [ "12","13","14" ];
   var damount = 1234;
   var donor_obj = {
       id : donor_data,
       amnt : damount,
   };
   jQuery.ajax({
       type:"POST",
       dataType : "json",
       url: myAjax.ajaxurl,
       data: { action : "my_action",
              'donors' :  JSON.stringify(donor_obj),
             },
       success:function(response){
                   console.log("success " );
                   //console.log("success " + JSON.parse(response));
                   jQuery("#d_amount").val(donor_data[0]);
                   jQuery("#p_button").text("brrr");
                },
       error: function(response) {
                   console.log("error" + response);
              },
       });
       });
});
```

## server side code

```
function ajx_add_donations () {
        global $wpdb;
        $adv_don=json_decode($_REQUEST['donors']);
        //$adv_don = json_decode($_POST['donors']);
        //echo json_encode("phani");
        //echo json_encode($result);
        $dtype = 'OFFLINE';
        $d_status = 'PENDING';
        $ddate = current_time( 'mysql' );
        $donation_e = array (
                        'UID' => $adv_don->id[0],
                        'STATUS' => $d_status,
                        'PMODE'  => $dtype,
                        'AMNT'   => $adv_don->amnt,
                        'DDATE'  => $ddate
                );

                $d_id = update_donation_entry($donation_e);
                echo json_encode("<h3> Thank you for Contribution <strong>$amount</strong></h3>");

        wp_die();

}
```

## Info needed

1. I'm not able to see my data base being updated, when I click the button,How to parse the Json data (array) at server side ?
2. Is there any way to know what I have received at server side, If I use "echo" to print a variable it is sent to ajax client ?
3. If answer to #2 is "NO" , how to parse the JSON data at client side ?

Comment: Can you perhaps limit your post to one question, and update your (rather confusing) title accordingly?  Rather post a second question.

Comment: myAjax.ajaxurl     how you are getting value of this property?

Comment: Basically I'm not able to read the JSON data at server side, this is the main issue , rest of the mentioned items are what I think probable causes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
       jQuery("#p_button").click ( function () {
       console.log("button got clicked");
       var donor_data= [ "12","13","14" ];
       var damount = 1234;
       var donor_obj = {
           id : donor_data,
           amnt : damount,
       };
       jQuery.ajax({
           type:"POST",
           //dataType : "json",
           url: myAjax.ajaxurl,
           data: { action : "ajx_add_donations",
              'donors' :  JSON.stringify(donor_obj),
             },
           success:function(response){
               console.log("success " ,response);
               //console.log("success " + JSON.parse(response));
               //jQuery("#d_amount").val(donor_data[0]);
               //jQuery("#p_button").text("brrr");
            },
           error: function(response) {
               console.log("error" + response);
              },
           });
           });
    });



    function ajx_add_donations () {


    global $wpdb;
        $adv_don=json_decode(stripslashes($_REQUEST['donors']));
        //$adv_don = json_decode($_POST['donors']);
        //echo json_encode("phani");
        //echo json_encode($result);
        $dtype = 'OFFLINE';
        $d_status = 'PENDING';
        $ddate = current_time( 'mysql' );
        $donation_e = array (
                    'UID' => $adv_don->id[0],
                    'STATUS' => $d_status,
                    'PMODE'  => $dtype,
                    'AMNT'   => $adv_don->amnt,
                    'DDATE'  => $ddate
            );

            $d_id = update_donation_entry($donation_e);
            echo json_encode("<h3> Thank you for Contribution <strong>$amount</strong></h3>");

        wp_die();

    }

    add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajx_add_donations','ajx_add_donations' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajx_add_donations', 'ajx_add_donations');
```

Comment: just comment the datatype in ajax script and print the request. you can see the post data in console.

Comment: Hi Vel, Thankyou for the repsonse, I'm able to see the object on console. Do you think if I'm accessing the JSON object correctly in PHP code "$adv_don=json_decode($_REQUEST["donors"]); $adv_don->amnt"

Comment: then, what is the issue?

Comment: answer updated. i just modified this line `$adv_don=json_decode(stripslashes($_REQUEST['donors']));`

Comment: by adding this "$adv_don=json_decode(stripslashes($_REQUEST['donors']));". I'm seeing error in console ERROR : "POST http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Comment: im getting this response. no error. https://i.stack.imgur.com/HO3Ap.png. please post your full code.

Comment: Hi Vel, I got the issue, as we were using decoded object as associative array , json_decode() needs second argument as "true".Thankyou very much i was suffering from the issue since 2days.